# Find the non null columns in SQL Server in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have read many answers but they are all for PL/SQL or Oracle, I could not find anything for Microsoft SQL-Server.

My table :

```
CREATE TABLE StudentScore
(
  Student_ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
  Student_Name NVARCHAR (50),
  Student_Score INT
) 

GO

INSERT INTO StudentScore VALUES (1,'Ali', NULL)
INSERT INTO StudentScore VALUES (2,'Zaid', 770)
INSERT INTO StudentScore VALUES (3,'Mohd', 1140)
INSERT INTO StudentScore VALUES (4,NULL, 770)
INSERT INTO StudentScore VALUES (5,'John', 1240)
INSERT INTO StudentScore VALUES (6,'Mike', 1140)
INSERT INTO StudentScore VALUES (7,'Goerge', NULL)
```

1. How to find the names of all the non-null columns.
2. Return table containing only non null columns

**EDIT based on comments:**

I am aware of `IS_NULLABLE` attribute of `Information_schema` . But just because a column allows null values does not mean it will actually have null values. How to find out columns which actually have null values.

I am looking for some `num_nulls` equivalent for microsoft SQL-SERVER.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve it by issuing:

```
SELECT 
  FORMATMESSAGE('SELECT col = ''%s.%s.%s'' FROM %s.%s HAVING COUNT(*) != COUNT(%s)', 
     QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA),
     QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME),
     QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME),
     QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA),
     QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME),
     QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME)
  )
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE IS_NULLABLE = 'YES';
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5f3ca4b795a617838e0e6bcb2c9cd018)**

It will generate script for checking individual column.

```
HAVING COUNT(*) != COUNT(col_name) -- it means that column contains at least single NULL

HAVING COUNT(col_name) = 0 AND COUNT(*) != 0 -- it means all values in columns are NULL
```

This approach could be polished with using `STRING_AGG` to get single query per table and with dynamic SQL you could avoid the need of copying the query.

### EDIT:

Fully baked-solution:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @sql = STRING_AGG(
  FORMATMESSAGE('SELECT table_schema = ''%s''
                        ,table_name = ''%s''
                        ,table_col_name = ''%s'' 
                        ,row_num = COUNT(*)
                        ,row_num_non_nulls = COUNT(%s)
                        ,row_num_nulls = COUNT(*) - COUNT(%s)
                 FROM %s.%s', 
     QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA),
     QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME),
     QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME),
     QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME),
     QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME),
     QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA),
     QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME),
     QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME)), ' UNION ALL' + CHAR(13)
               ) WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME)

FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE IS_NULLABLE = 'YES'
  AND TABLE_NAME = ?        -- filter by table name
  AND TABLE_SCHEMA = ?;     -- filter by schema name

SELECT @sql;
EXEC(@sql);
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4fed951e140bc664cad309d9e022a52d)**

Output:

```
+---------------+-----------------+------------------+----------+--------------------+---------------+
| table_schema  |   table_name    | table_col_name   | row_num  | row_num_non_nulls  | row_num_nulls |
+---------------+-----------------+------------------+----------+--------------------+---------------+
| [dbo]         | [StudentScore]  | [Student_Name]   |       7  |                 6  |             1 |
| [dbo]         | [StudentScore]  | [Student_Score]  |       7  |                 5  |             2 |
+---------------+-----------------+------------------+----------+--------------------+---------------+
```

Comment: I am getting error : incorrect syntax at `having`. I have added a table just for illustration. Can you modify your code acc to that table so that this is clear to me.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8116174727e374e704005e1ec37b4b07 -- None of the columns contains a single NULL

Comment: @ShailajaGuptaKapoor Having the output I provided you could perform any kind of filtering(all nulls, some nulls, non-nulls only and so on)

Comment: Hi Lukas, there is a problem if I execute this on a database with too many tables, I am getting `STRING_AGG aggregation result exceeded the limit of 8000 bytes. Use LOB types to avoid result truncation.
`. How can i customise this only for  one table in a db....What will the value of table schema for eg

Comment: @ShailajaGuptaKapoor Just add a filter on main query based on table name, like I did.

Comment: why we have not put information_schema and columns in quotename?

Comment: what is CHAR(13) and why it is added. I am new to advanced SQL. Pls help me

Comment: @CHAR(13) is carriage return symbol , quotename is function that quotes identifier => a becomes `[a]`. Btw removing upvote/unaccepting answer without providing comment is simply inappropriate.  SO is not a code service in a sense you will get production ready solution without any effort.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you want to look at [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/columns-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).  The column `IS_NULLABLE` provides this information.

Note that the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` tables (well, they are really views) are Standard SQL, so this information is available in most database.  Oracle has not (yet?) adopted them.

Comment: If a column is nullable, does not mean it will contain null values(it may or may not have null values ). I am aware of information_schema. My question is that lets say a column can have null values, and actually has null values too, then how to know

Comment: @ShailajaGuptaKapoor . . . I interpreted your question to be about the *definitions* of the columns.  Without sample data and desired results, that seems like a very reasonable interpretation.

Comment: Ok great, now that you know what I wanted, kindly help me