# Run a for loop with variables from a list in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, for-loop, variables

im trying to run this query with multiple table_name, column_name, int1, and int2.

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column_name = REPLACE(column_name, "int1", "int2")
WHERE column_name like "int1%"
```

Is there a simple way to create a list and run a for loop like in other languages?

Here is a simple python script of basically what I would like to do in SQL:

```
list1 = ["foo", "bar"]
list2 = ["foo2", "bar2"]
list3 = [1, 2]
list4 = [3, 4]
for i in len(list1):
     print(list1[i],list2[i],list3[i],list4[i])
```

Im sorry I am very new to SQL, and could not find exactly something like this elsewhere.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Generally speaking, a table that has repeating column names is (or will soon be) a big coding problem. It would be better to properly normlize your tables.

Comment: With what I was hoping to do, a single table wouldn't have repeating column names, although different tables would share column names.

Answer (score 1):

You could generate it as:

```
SELECT 
    query_to_run = FORMATMESSAGE(
'UPDATE %s.%s
 SET %s = REPLACE(%s, ''int1'', ''int2'')'
    ,QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA)
    ,QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)
    ,QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME)
    ,QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) 
   )
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = ?
  AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'int1%';
```

Similiar TSQL pattern for generating and running code: [Find the non null columns in SQL Server in a table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61426841/5070879)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Im assuming I am creating a new schema with the list of variables, and I've tried a couple variations but could not seem to get it to work. Sorry for the elementary question but where would I put my list of table_names, column_names, int1s, and int2s?